# Azure Blueprint parameter requires a value of type 'Bool'

Tags: azure

i have an assignment file for a blueprint that deploys a storage account
running the assignment i get "Blueprint parameter "resource" requires a value of type 'Bool'"

this runs manually fine via the console - but psh deployment with a param file (new New-AzBlueprintAssignment) i cannot seem to pass a bool value from the parameter file into the blueprint
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGylA.png)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the definition parameter file for assignment specifies Boolean values as:

```
"value": true
```

and not:

```
"value": "true"
```